# How can I synchronize load cell and sensor for sensor calibration?

Tags: arduino, sensor, load-cell, synchronization

I have made a glove with some cheap pressure sensors with weight ∝ 1/resistance.

[image]

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I now want to create a dataset with columns "Actual Weight" and "Glove Sensor Readout" so that I can fit a calibration model to the glove sensor.

**LOAD CELL FOR Actual Weight Column**

The usual ethod is to:

1. Apply 5 known weights to the glove sensor
2. Record the output.
3. Fit the model.

Instead I thought of wearing the glove and applying a force onto a load cell. This would give many more data points.

I have never used a load cell and am unsure about:

1. Time synchronization between glove pressure sensor and load cell.
2. Delay between applied force on the load cell and cell response.
   Basically if the weight data I record with the  Arduino while I increase/decrease pressure with my finger is accurate.

**METHOD**

1. Connect Arduino to a load cell via the HX711 load cell amplifier (`[as found here][1]`)
2. Press the glove pixel sensor on the load cell, going up slowly (For example: 0-40N in 5 seconds.)
3. Read out the sensor with its own electronics (already made.)
4. View load cell (actual weight) and glove sensor signals vs time on PC and synchronize them. They should form the same pattern.
5. Plot sensor signal vs load cell, and fit the model to calibrate the sensor (basic model is a linear fit.)

[image]

**Questions**:

1. Is a load cell with an Arduino setup fast enough to be able to accurately synchronize the weight on cell with the output of the glove pressure sensor?
2. How slow do I ramp up (0-40N in **x** seconds?)
3. Is there any better setups/pieces you can recommend? (load cell type, different amplifier, **MCU** etc.)

Comment: So you went through all the effort of creating that glove, but you are still using cheap hobbyist boards for MCU. How does that make sense? Though if you ask me the question "should I use Arduino" the answer is always no, no matter the context. It's bad for learning and worse for everything else.

Comment: @Lundin, we are material physicists here, so we worked on the sensors,  but know very little about the best MCUs. Haven't built the Arduino project yet, it was just one of the first projects we found. Do you have any suggestions for Setup pieces (load cell, MCU, etc) ?

Comment: @Lundin, I have added "MCU" to the list in Question 3, as before it was unclear that even the Arduino can be changed

Comment: Those who aren't used at working with electronics for some reason always seem to think getting a board with a MCU on is the hard problem to solve :) It is not, there's tons of evaluation boards and even making a custom board isn't a big deal. As for what to pick, I'd say it depends on the nature of the load cell, there's lots of different types. Perhaps you need lots of ADC, perhaps you need I2C or SPI etc etc. Not very exotic requirements. If you plan on doing somewhat advanced math with floating points then go for a Cortex M4 or bigger.

Comment: However, with the current component shortage crisis, we have to throw good engineering out the window as just specify a MCU - any MCU - that can be purchased in the real world. I recently tried to specify a MCU for a project and came up with no less than 6 different alternatives, all highly recommended part status. Not a single one of them exists in the physical world.

Comment: Yeah everything with any electronics is hard to get now, the waiting times are crazy. I work with the Electrical Engineering department at Uni, so hopefully they will have something lying around :), if not we will make do with the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

To me, your proposed methodology is correct. I would just go for it.

Few points to consider:

1. An Arduino Uno could be a bit too slow if you want to avoid slow processing "bottlenecks". Use an ESP32 or a Teensy Board instead.
2. Familiarize with the HX711 chip. It can be very very slow if the algorithm is flawed. Make sure to properly calibrate it using known weights (good quality ones and tested with a lab-grade scale for validation)
3. When pressing the load cell with the glove do at least 3 runs per finger for standard deviation purposes and validation of your resulting data.
4. Regarding the ramp-up speed, do it at a reasonable speed, based on the visual feedback you get from the serial plotter. It is difficult to estimate a speed without knowing the characteristic of your final instrumentation.